# 403 error when opening PDF with chrome pdf viewer

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, http-status-code-403

We host C# 3.5 net web app in ISS 7.5.

PDF files are generated and put in some directory. Listing of directory is disabled. With all browsers (IE10, FF, Opera...) we can access the PDF.

When accessing the URL with Chrome, PDF is loaded... then we get a 403 error. If we disable chrome internal pdf viewer and tell it to use Adobe's, it works fine.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is explained here: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/1mSjCjabwPE

But the mentioned KB cannot be applied so we'll do with some `HttpHandler`.

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        switch (context.Request.HttpMethod)
        {
            case "GET":

                if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
                    return;
                }


                string requestedFile = context.Server.MapPath(context.Request.FilePath);

                context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                context.Response.TransmitFile(context.Server.MapPath(context.Request.FilePath));
                context.Response.End();

                break;
        }
    }
```